# Trouble with node-fetch Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

So I'm trying to build a weather app by using data from a weather API.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

//fetch weather API
let weather
let getWeather = async() => {
let url = \https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=auckland&appid=c156947e2c7f0ccb0e2a20fde1d2c577`try {let res = await fetch(url)weather = await res.json()    } catch (error) {console.log("error")    } let weatherMain = weather.weather.map( el => el.description)if(weatherMain ="Rain"){console.log(weatherMain)// weatherImg = "[https://icon-library.com/images/raining-icon/raining-icon-1.jpg](https://icon-library.com/images/raining-icon/raining-icon-1.jpg)"    }  }console.log(getWeather())`
```

My problem is that I'm getting this error when running in vscode:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

and this error when running in browser:

`` Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "node-fetch". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` ``

Not sure what exactly is going on, Can someone please explain what's happening?

I've tried fetch API once before and that time I didn't need to import fetch, so I'm pretty confused.

SS

Edit - Understood now, running in browser and in vscode is 2 different things. What works in the browser won't necessarily work in Node.js
When running in browser, there's no need to import fetch.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Fundamentally, the problem here is that you are following a tutorial for writing JS to run in Node.js and then trying to run it in a browser.

Comment: I think VSCode will try and run it as a browser. Not as node?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let weather;
let getWeather = async () => {
  let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=auckland&appid=c156947e2c7f0ccb0e2a20fde1d2c577`;
  try {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    weather = await res.json();
    console.log('weather', weather);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  let weatherMain = weather.weather.map((el) => el.description);
  if ((weatherMain = 'Rain')) {
    console.log('weatherMain', weatherMain);
    let weatherImg =
      '[https://icon-library.com/images/raining-icon/raining-icon-1.jpg](https://icon-library.com/images/raining-icon/raining-icon-1.jpg)';
    return weatherImg;
  }
};

const main = async () => {
  const data = await getWeather();
  console.log('data', data);
};

main();
```

Yes, you are right about no need to import fetch if you are running the js in the browser. But I see that you are importing `node-fetch`, this package is used to bring the fetch (window.fetch) for the node system.

But If you want to run it in the node, then you should know that the node doesn't support ES6 module. But you can user the experimental flag to run the code. e.g.
`node --experimental-modules app.mjs`

Comment: "But If you want to run it in the node, then you should know that the node doesn't support ES6 module. But you can user the experimental flag to run the code" — ECMAScript module support for Node.js has been stable, and not needed the experimental flag, since Node 12